# add column with value from a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 strings in an array.  I also have a dataframe with a column of values 0-2.  I want to add a new column with the result of evaluating the list[x].

So far I have the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn import datasets

iris_raw = datasets.load_iris()
iris = pd.DataFrame(iris_raw.data, columns=iris_raw.feature_names)

iris = pd.concat([iris, pd.DataFrame(iris_raw.target)], axis = 1)

vals = iris_raw.target_names

def eval_dummy(tgt_dum):
    default = np.nan
    return(iris_raw.target_names[tgt_dum] if 0 <= tgt_dum <= len(vals) else default)

vec_eval_dumm = np.vectorize(eval_dummy)

iris = pd.concat([iris, pd.DataFrame(vec_eval_dumm(np.array(iris.iloc[:, 4])))], axis = 1)

iris.columns.values[5] = 'species'

print(iris.head())
```

This is far from pretty, is there a better way to do this?

- I have recreated my problem with the iris data set, so feel free to run the code to see what I'm trying to do.
- naturally I've tried googling this, but I'm not finding anything pertinent using phrases like 'evaluate variable'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to **[map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) the integer to the target name**?

```
# NumPy rather than pandas concatenation might be a bit quicker
iris = np.concatenate((iris_raw.data, iris_raw.target[:, None]), axis=1)
iris = pd.DataFrame(iris, columns=iris_raw.feature_names + ['tgt_num'])
mapped = dict(zip([0, 1, 2], iris_raw.target_names))
iris.loc[:, 'species'] = iris.tgt_num.map(mapped)

print(iris)
#    sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  petal length (cm)  petal width (cm)  \
# 0                5.1               3.5                1.4               0.2   
# 1                4.9               3.0                1.4               0.2   
# 2                4.7               3.2                1.3               0.2   
# 3                4.6               3.1                1.5               0.2   
# 4                5.0               3.6                1.4               0.2   
# 
#    tgt_num  species  
# 0      0.0   setosa  
# 1      0.0   setosa  
# 2      0.0   setosa  
# 3      0.0   setosa  
# 4      0.0   setosa
```